# convergence and bounds

Tags: calculus

To prove uniform convergence of a series, I am trying to show that the $|f_n - f|_\infty \to 0 $

$\bigg|\frac{1}{n + x^2} \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{|n + x^2|} \leq \frac{1}{n - x^2}$

Having trouble getting rid of x from the upper bound? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|n+x^2| \geq |n|$ you can bound $\frac{1}{|n+x^2|} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ (for $n\geq 0$ of course)